# scipy optimize solution closest to initial guess

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I am trying to use scipy.optimize.minimize to obtain a solution for the following problem:

Say we are given f(x,y) = x + 2*y, and we have an initial guess of (1,1). We want to solve f(x,y) = 0, but for my goals, any solution that gives me |f(x,y)| < tolerance is good enough. Obviously there are infinite many solutions, so my question was: Is there an algorithm in optimize.minimize such that it gives priority to the closest (euclidean distance) solution? That is, I am imagining start from the initial guess, and searching in a circle around the initial guess, if there is no solution, the radius increases, but once it hits a point that is within the tolerance, then it returns that point.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there's at least one solution for the equation f(x,y) = 0. Then you could formulate it as a constrained optimization problem to get the solution closest to the given initial guess:

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import numpy as np

# We want to minimize ||f(x)-xinit|| subject to f(x) = 0

f = lambda x: x[0] + 2*x[1]
# the euclidean norm of f-xinit
objfun = lambda x, xinit: np.sqrt(np.sum((f(x)-xinit)**2))

# initial guess
xinit = [1, 1]
# constraint f(x) = 0:
constr = {"type": "eq", "fun": f}
minimize(fun=objfun, args=(xinit,), x0=xinit, constraints=constr)
```

In the case of no solution for the equation f(x,y)=0, you could try to minimize |f(x,y)| without any constraints.